# How to write a systemmd script to run an ember server?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Currently to start the server i type ember s. How do i put this in systemmd script to start it automatically ? I need to write a systemmd (Ubuntu 16.04) script to automatically start the ember server which i start using ember s. Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

The `ember s` is **NOT designed** to be run to serve your Ember app in production. There are quite likely major security vulnerabilities you would expose your server to by doing so.

Instead, if you run `ember build --environment=production` and put the files produced on your server, you should be set.

Comment: Can you link me to a tutorial which does the same ? Thanks

Comment: The Ember quick start or tutorial both discuss deploying. Have you checked those?

Comment: Ohk will check it. Will get back here in case i get any doubts.

Comment: For reference, here is the relevant section: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/tutorial/deploying/